# PHP __construct() inheritance not working

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, subclass

I have been banging my head against the wall for more than a hour now, looking for solutions on the internet (including stackoverflow), but couldn't really find any help, so I decided to ask you guys.

I have the following **classes.php** file

```
<?php

class System {

    public $domain;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->domain = 'http://google.com';
    }

    public function getDomain() {
        echo $this->domain;
    }

}

class User extends System {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->domain);
    }

    public function getDomain() {
        echo $this->domain;
    }

}
```

And my code for the **index.php** file is:

```
$system = new System();
$user = new User();
$system->getDomain();
$user->getDomain();
```

Now, the above solution works, but it does not really what I need.
I need for the System class __construct() to be as follows:

```
public function __construct($domain) {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }
```

And I want to be able to dynamically set the domain from the index.php page, like:

```
$system = new System('http://google.com');
```

### So to recap everything:

I want to be able to set the domain from my constructor, like so:

```
public function __construct($domain) {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }
```

instead of

```
public function __construct() {
            $this->domain = 'http://google.com';
        }
```

Comment: $this->domain is undefined at the time you in instantiate System

Comment: For a start `System::__construct` does not take a parameter

Comment: `I want to be able to set the domain from my constructor, like so: [...]` - What's stopping you? That's a reasonable change and should do what you want it to (if you change it in all neccessary places) if you explained your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is that I do not understand very well what you want to do, but I would do it this way.

```
 class System {

        private $domain;

        protected function __construct($domain) {
            $this->domain = $domain;
        }

        protected function getDomain() {
            return $this->domain;
        }

    }

    class User extends System {

        public function __construct($domain) {
            parent::__construct($domain);
        }


    }

$user = new User('http://google.com');
echo $user->getDomain();
```